# How i get response from ASYNC SOAP webservice in .net core?

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-core, soap

Firstly im newbie in .net core and soap webserive in .net.
We're working on a project about requesting data from SOAP-Based webserive(from WSDL). Maybe the question seems so easy or wierd, i apologize for that.

Here i draw our system:
[image]

The system works like that, first client request a save request from our web API, and we're add some authentication information for SOAP webservice and query from SOAP webservice. Than SOAP webservice returns a unique queryNumber to query results at a later date. Problem is that i couldnt get queryNumber from response.

i added references via WSDL adress using WCF webservice provider and all methods are implemented in references : **saveRequest**(paramaters, userid for auth., pass for auth.), **saveResponse**(queryNumber), **saveAsync**(same as saveRequest). saveAsync method calls saveRequest already.

The usage of saveAsync is seems in reference like:

```
ServiceClient.saveResponse = await ServiceClient.saveAsync(params);
```

So i wrote that code:

```
static async Task<ServiceClient.saveResponse> _run (params){
   Service.ServiceClient = new Service.ServiceClient();
   ServiceClient.saveResponse getResult= await ServiceClient.saveAsync(params);
   return getResult;
}
```

And than i called this Async method in main or somewhere. But when i called that async method and tried to get queryNumber, I got Internal Server Error (500).

Actually im sending parameters using FormBody (with XML).

I tried same task using SOAPUI and get result XML without any error. Also i tracked code and it's seen that the code stuck in exactly in there:

```
ServiceClient.saveResponse getResult= await ServiceClient.saveAsync(params);
```

I'm not sure did i use code block correctly. Do you see any wrong block about code ? or misuse ? Maybe i used async method wrongly but saveAsync wants code blocks exactly like this.

thank you in advance.

Edit 1 : Our 3rd party SOAP web starting with **HTTPS://...** . is error relevant to that ?

Comment: Sever error 500 as the message indicates means that the error occurred at the server side and so the error message was returned so you might want to debug and inspect the logs there to see why the request is failing and once that is solved see if your client is retrieving the data correctly (the code you posted looks good to me).

Comment: @Isma thanks for response. But when i use SOAPUI and send data it's responding correctly. Also, should i write any code about connection of SOAP ? Because i didnt write any code about SOAP or HTTP connection, because WCF connection load all methods already.

Answer (score 0):

I had the solution. The problem was about .Net Core 2.0 version or System.ServiceModel.Http version. I applied steps in [Connecting to a SOAP service with .Net Core 2.0 behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47183067/connecting-to-a-soap-service-with-net-core-2-0-behind-a-proxy/) and problem is solved.